# Google Sheets - Move row to new sheet based on drop down value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have posted this before with my own script and I got some amazing responses but they didn't work fully I am hoping someone can help with a better script

[image: Sample Sheet]

The columns will stay the same but I will load data into the area. I am looking to have it when you select the option 'List 1' or 'List 2' or Etc in the Assigned to the column it will move the row to a page with that same name. The new sheets will have the same headers at the top. I can get it to work myself for the one list but I am at a loss for how to make it for multiple lists.

I am hoping to find one that either works on edit or after running the script.

Thanks in advance and please ask any questions I will do my best to answer

Comment: on you trigger, get the edited assigned, if the assigned is your permitted name, for example List 1, you check this assigned name to sheets collection, if not found, create new, then copy this row to the new assigned sheet, and delete this row from the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Your Sheet Name' && e.range.columnStart==6)  {
    var v=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName(e.value);
    if(tsh) {
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,v[0].length).setValues(v);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! this might be a stretch is there a way to make it run on existing sections in column 6 as well or allow be to paste the same result in multiple columns and move?

Comment: I can probably help you but it’s not clear to me exactly what you’re asking for. Can you be more specific.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide an example with data showing me where you want to move it from and move it to

Comment: Sorry for the delay I have been away. Here is a copy link if that help of an example of the sheet [SAMPLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17EJPfUGvnIudsZO2M6UD1n17RIXRhghVykGTSgDGO0o/copy)